# Find users with a particular license in Azure Graph REST

Tags: rest, azure, graph

Has anyone queried the Azure Graph REST API by licenses?  I can't find any examples using REST online.  We use REST for our operations and a need has come up to generate license reports and I'd like to be able to execute queries based on license codes.

Any help would be appreciate.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you’d like to filter users by **assignedLicenses** that is a multi-valued complex type. From [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), we could find that currently the API seems not support querying of (filtering) a multi-valued complex type (assignedLicenses).

As a workaround, you could try to get users from API and leave the filtering on the client side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this reply.  Yeah, I have code that does this on client filtering but our tenant in the cloud has over 200K user objects so its painful.  Frustrating that MS doesn't offer this.  But I appreciate you taking the time to respond.